# Use plain text Widget for Spyder's IPython Console

Tags: configuration, jupyter, spyder, plaintext, qtconsole

I'm able to set Jupyter's QtConsole to use a plaintext widget instead of rich text by setting this

```
c.JupyterQtConsoleApp.plain = True
```

in the configuration file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_qtconsole_config.py`

Spyder's IPython Console does not seem to respect the settings in this configuration file. How do I set this option (or get the same behavior) for Spyder's IPython Console?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder only uses rich text widgets in its consoles, so it doesn't respect the config option you mention (although it tries to respect most of the others).

I really don't understand why you would like to use plain text widgets instead, but if you want that possibility, there's always `qtconsole`, as you point out.

Comment: My principle motivation is that the rendering of output of pint objects is poor and slow since it sends it through a LaTeX interpreter (pint is a units package). See [here](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/616) for an example. I've been using Spyder for 7+ years, since _before_ Pierre integrated QtConsole, and have no desire to change ;-). I'd like to explore other solutions.

Comment: I don't know how to help you about that. Perhaps you could talk with Pint developers to see how to improve things for Spyder. You could ping me on Github if I can help with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this issue which is to delete the `_repr_latex_` methods defined by pint. In an `__init__.py` where I instantiate a unit registry to be used throughout a project I have the following:

```
import pint
ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()

# don't display latex in consoles
delattr(pint.quantity._Quantity, '_repr_latex_')
delattr(pint.unit._Unit, '_repr_latex_')
```

This should be safe since methods of the pattern `_repr_<meme>_` are only used by `IPython.display` module.